# How to do a cloth simulation in Blender?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have the following scene:

[image: Scene Example]

I applied the cloth simulation property to the cloth that is floating over the sphere. When the scene is animated, the cloth goes right through the ball.

How do I make a realistic simulation?

Comment: this seems too much like a request for tutorial.

Comment: For future reference see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/12 -- Overly broad topics and lengthy howtos are off-topic.

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-would-be-wrong-with-tutorials-as-long-as-they-describe-a-reusable-workflow - this should be reopened.

Comment: After discussion I understand why it was closed. I just suggest we tell the user why.

Comment: This is a valid question. And the answer is "Select the UV sphere and directly navigate to physics tab again and select collision in the first column, second row" as suggested by Aditia bellow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to create two geometry first are UV sphere and plane. Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to add a mesh. Now select the plane mesh and go to edit mode (press <kbd>tab</kbd>) select all (press <kbd>a</kbd>) then press <kbd>w</kbd> to call special menu and select subdivide. I prefer to increase the number of cuts to 10 (more are better but slower).

After this you can optionally add modifier subsurf and turn on shading smooth, for better look of the cloth.

Next, go back to object mode and with the plane still selected, navigate to physic tab in the property panel. Select **cloth** in the first column, third row.

Then select the UV sphere and directly navigate to physic tab again and select **collision** in the first column, second row.

Now you can start play the animation by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or the play button in timeline. The cloth sims now should start.

Comment: Worked great! You should add 'turn on smooth shading on the cloth' especially if you are only using 10 subdivisions.

Comment: How can I move the cloth upwards while still maintaining the look of the simulation?